# How to retrieve a cell value and write it in another sheet checking two different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets, Progress and App1stSession, in the same spreadsheet.

Progress sheet has these columns

> Date Campaign Sessions 1stSessions

App1stSession sheet these columns

> Date Campaign 1stSessions

I need to retrieve 1stSessions values from App1stSession. The match can be done on Date and Campaign values.
I've written this formula

```
INDEX(App1stSession!$A$1:C, 
AND(MATCH($B1,App1stSession!$B$1:B,0),MATCH($A1,App1stSession!$A$1:A,0))),3)
```

Of course it doesn't work because AND retrieves 0 or 1.
So I've tried this solution

```
INDEX(App1stSession!$A$1:C,IF(AND(MATCH($B1,App1stSession!$B$1:C,0),MATCH($A1
,App1stSession!$A$1:A,0)),MATCH($C1,App1stSession!$C$1:C,0)),3)
```

I suppose that the second MATCH could retrieve the right row: neither this solution works.
Finally I've tried

```
=QUERY(App1stSession!$A$1:A,"SELECT """&App1stSession!$C1:C&""" WHERE 
("""&App1stSession!$A$1:A&"""="""&$A1&""")AND("""&App1stSession!$B$1:B&"""="""&$C1&""")")
```

Again it doesn't work but I suppose because of a matter of syntax.
Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, is insert one unique id column/search key in column A, before the rest of your data, that is dynamically created by the date & campaign values in your App1stSession sheet:

```
=B1&C1
```

then use this type of formula to smush the same two values together dynamically on your search sheet in a vlookup fashion on your progress sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&B1,App1stSession!A:D,4,false)
```

Comment: Thanks Aurielle but it doesn't work. For what I know vlookup searches in the first column of the interval and it will never find the value A&B.

Comment: @AndreaM do you have a sample sheet you can share, im 100% more effective if i can try a formula or two

Comment: @AndreaM that is why I suggested that you add a helper column before the rest of the data you want to pull and give that column the value of =B1&C1 thus creating a unique id by which you can query with vlookup